# Efficiently iterating over the contents of a large text file, preserving newlines

Tags: c++, csv, text

I have some large text files that are too big to (sensibly) read into memory.

I would like to iterate over the characters in the files (for the purposes of removing some undesired sequences of characters), preserving any newline (`\n`) sequences.

For example, I would like to read:

```
ab|cd|ef
gh|i
j|kl
```

as:

```
ab|cd|ef\ngh|i\nj|kl
```

For the purposes of removing all but the *last* newline sequence which is not preceded by at least `x` occurrences of a delimiter, where `x` is some expected number of columns.

To illustrate this better, consider the following example with the number of columns, `x`, as 3. To be explicit, we'll want to replace all newlines *after* the second delimiter, before the last newline before another delimiter or the end of the file is encountered:

```
fruit|colour|notes
apple|red|
orange|orange|i
like
them
grapes|red
sometimes|tasty
```

Into:

```
fruit|colour|notes
apple|red|
orange|orange|i like them
grapes|red sometimes|tasty
```

This could be either in place or a copy.

**What might be the preferred ways of doing this with C++?** Questions and answers I've looked at so far seem to only stream lines or read (*slurp*?) the entire file (though it's possible I misunderstand some of the answers).

Comment: The best way to read the file depends greatly on the processing you intend to do, which unfortunately you have not really specified. But however you read the file I don't see that newlines present any particular problem, newlines are just characters like any other character.

Comment: Thanks @john, and good point. I'll update the question when I get a moment.

Comment: Don't forget the possibility of reading the file one character at a time. For many tasks this will be simple and efficient.

Comment: I've updated the question -- hopefully that will help clarify my issue. It's possible there is an answer already, I'm just not entirely sure what the correct search terms would be.

Comment: "seem to only stream lines " - you can easily stream characters. That's what an ifstream does by default.

Comment: If you are only changing `'\n'` (newline) characters to `' '` (space) characters, and you are on a POSIX operating system (e.g. Linux), then you are not changing the length of the file. In that case, it should not be a problem to make the modifications in-place. However, if you are using Microsoft Windows, then it could be a problem, because that operating system uses `"\r\n"` instead of `"\n"` line endings.

Comment: What you're doing is changing \n into space except for the last one before a | - which means when you get a | you have to go back and undo the last one. So it's not a pure streaming algorithm and it is necessary to look ahead some unknown distance. You could simply say that you promise they won't be longer than say 4k bytes, then use a 4kB buffer; or for simplicity you might find it easier to use mmap and the OS will manage the buffering (not optimally).

Comment: Does this do what you wanted? https://onlinegdb.com/2qaWGKq8d7  It doesn't store the whole file but it does stream lines.

Answer (score 0):

Please do not blame me for my answer. I just suggested some approx solution.

I can suggest a bash solution for this

```bash
cat in.csv | awk 'BEGIN { prev_line="" } /\|/ { print prev_line; prev_line=$0 } !/\|/ { prev_line = prev_line" "$0 } END { print prev_line }' > file.out;
```

but this solution returns

```
fruit|colour|notes
apple|red|
orange|orange|i like them
grapes|red
sometimes|tasty
```

on your example.

I actually do not figured out clearly the rule when you want to replace `'\n'` with `' '`. And why in `grapes|red\nsometimes|tasty` `'\n'` should be replaced with `' '`.

Comment: I appreciate this -- I should clarify the question example further. A key bit of missing information is that there should be 3 columns, which means we can delete all `\n` before the final one following the second delimiter. I'll add it to the question, apologies for the oversight.

Answer (score 0):

Each new "row" consists of 3 original rows, and each original row now split by `\f (form feed \x0C \014)` instead of by `\n`, which you can restore back as `\n` once you're done processing.

It works just as well with `gawk` in `UTF-8` mode, since it absolutely doesn't matter that

> ```
> ORS = "\371\37\1\301"
> ```

is not `UTF-8`-compliant at all - it's only to aid with inter-row delineation between pipes, and wouldn't show up in the output, nor trigger any warning message. Not being `UTF-8`-compliant is actually a plus since the likelihood of it existing in any text data is practically zero.

```
echo '
    ab|cd|ef
    gh|i|ihg
    j|kl|lkj
    mn|op|qr
    st|u|uts
    vw|x|xwv
    yzA|BC|D
    EF|G|GFE
    H|IJK|KJIH
    LMNO|PQ|RS' |
```

> ```
> mawk   'ORS = NR % 3 ? "\n" : "\371\37\1\301"'     | 
>
> gawk 'BEGIN { FS = "\n" ; RS = "\371\37\1\301|\n+$"
>               OFS = "\f" 
>             }   sub("^\f*",_, $!(NF = NF))'
> ```

```
     1  ab|cd|ef
                gh|i|ihg
                        j|kl|lkj
     2  mn|op|qr
                st|u|uts
                        vw|x|xwv
     3  yzA|BC|D
                EF|G|GFE
                        H|IJK|KJIH
     4  LMNO|PQ|RS
```